# Django urls dont work redirects to single url

Tags: python, html, django

All my urls in the app "products" redirects to products_list

```
urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import(
        product_list,
        search,
        add_product,
        category_single,
        manage_product_image,
        edit_product,
        download_product,
        single,

        )

app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', product_list, name='product-list'),
    url(r'^search/',search, name="search"),
    url(r'^add/',add_product,name='add_product'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<slug>.*)/$',category_single,name="category"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>.*)/images/',manage_product_image,name="manage_product_image"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>.*)/edit/',edit_product,name="edit_product"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>.*)/download/(?P<filename>.*)$',download_product,name="download_product"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>.*)/$',single,name="single_product"),
]
```

if i type `http://localhost:8000/products`  it sends me to the list of products which is perfect ,but typing `http://localhost:8000/products/add/` also sends me to the product list which is not perfect it should be to the form to add products.
views.py

```
def add_product(request):
    form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        product = form.save(commit=False)
        product.user =  request.user
        product.slug = slugify(form.cleaned_data['title'])
        product.active = False
        product.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/products/%s'%(product.slug))
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request,"products/edit.html",context)
```

I have tried to comment all lines of code in the view.py just to render the template still does not come through ,just brings the product list.

Comment: You forgot a `$` at the first item, this means the URL matches *everything*.

Comment: which items@Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first [**`url(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.url) pattern is a pattern that matches everything. Indeed the regex `^` matches all strings since you only specify the string start anchor.

You should add an *end of string anchor* (`$`) as well:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', product_list, name='product-list'),
    # ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first `url(r'^')`, you need to add an *end of string anchor ($)*
Like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', product_list, name='product-list'),
    # ... All other urls here.
]
```

Also why don't you use something like `path(r'^add/', add_product, name='add-product')`, where you *don't* need an *end of string anchor ($)* like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import(
        product_list,
        search,
        add_product,
        category_single,
        manage_product_image,
        edit_product,
        download_product,
        single,

        )

app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^$', product_list, name='product-list'),
    path(r'search/',search, name="search"),
    path(r'add/',add_product,name='add_product'),
    path(r'category/(?P<slug>.*)/$',category_single,name="category"),
    path(r'(?P<slug>.*)/images/',manage_product_image,name="manage_product_image"),
    path(r'(?P<slug>.*)/edit/',edit_product,name="edit_product"),
    path(r'(?P<slug>.*)/download/(?P<filename>.*)$',download_product,name="download_product"),
    path(r'(?P<slug>.*)/$',single,name="single_product"),
]
```